# Upgrade script not working

Tags: magento-1.9, module, upgrade-script

I've added two category attributes successfully to magento admin. However when I run an upgrade script to add another, "core_resource" takes note of my module update but doesn't install the new attribute.

Here is my `upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.2.php`

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();

$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'is_brand', array(
    'group'                     => 'Display Settings',
    'type'                      => 'int',
    'input'                     => 'select',
    'source'                    => '',
    'label'                     => 'Is a brand?',
    'backend'                   => '',
    'visible'                   => 1,
    'required'                  => 0,
    'user_defined'              => 999,
    'default'                   => 0,
    'global'                    => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

and as mentioned I updated config.xml to `<version>1.0.2</version>`

Nothing is added to the admin panel, no errors, no log errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: check in core_resource table for your module version,,,or try to clear cache,,,

Comment: Hey, as mentioned above core_resource takes note of my module update and cache is not enabled.

Comment: whats your current version in core_Resource table ?

Comment: and your upgrade script name should be mysql4-upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.2

Comment: Current version is 1.0.2 in core_resource, also hasn't the use of mysql been deprecated?

Comment: the try to change 1.0.1 and clear your cache and run your store again

Comment: I've tried that multiple times to no avail :/

Comment: then delete entry from core_resource and try it works

Comment: Hey I've sorted it, please see answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26343/discussion-between-keyur-shah-and-stefkay).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comment your file name should be

The second script name was not correct

```
upgrade-1.0.1.php
    upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.2
```

Comment: That is not the answer.

Comment: @Stefkay i have updated my answer thanks to pointing

Answer (score 2):

i've sorted this.

Problem was I had:

install-1.0.0.php
**upgrade-1.0.1.php**
upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.2.php

The second script name was not correct and was breaking the chain of running scripts.

Thanks to **Keyur Shah** his help led me to solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the reason why it was not triggered is that I had different version in the table `core_resource` from the xml version from `config.xml`.

In my case, the xml version was `1.4.0` and in the databse I had `1.4.2`

I posted this, so it might help others facing this issue. 
Thank you